# What franchises are these robots from?

Tags: character-identification

[image: Robots 1-6]
[image]
[image]

I know you guys love identifying things but we don't have any Robots! :D

Comment: Ones that people haven't already gotten: 10 is Pneuman from the "Tom Strong" comics by Alan Moore. 15 is Woody Allen impersonating a robot butler from the movie "Sleeper". 24 is Brainiac from the DC animated universe.

Comment: You effort is appreciated :) @Hypnosifl

Comment: These kind of "questions" seem to be a better fit for Sporcle than for StackOverflow, IMHO.

Comment: @Junuxx This isn't "StackOverflow".

Comment: @Mast: Yeah yeah, [debatable](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). Besides, "The StackExchange Q&A Network" is such a mouthful.

Comment: Christmas competition at work?

Comment: @Peter I WISH!­

Comment: What's the source of this image?

Comment: @jwodder Graphic Artist [Daniel Nyari](http://iamdany.com/)

Comment: This post might be a better fit on [Puzzling.SE].

Comment: #26 is technically a cyborg, not a robot. Their brain is human, but they have an emotion suppression circuit to keep them from acting it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams #7 Is a boy in a cardboard box :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This image lists all of the characters in order. The text lists the characters and the year they first appeared. The work is by artist [Daniel Nyari](http://iamdany.com/), but this image of a poster isn't shown on his website. (There are [other versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD3l0.jpg) of the image, with the same text, but the heads in a different order, which screws up the readability.)

[image: Famous Robots by Daniel Nyari]

Going left-to-right, these are robots, followed by the franchises or single works they appear in:

Row 1:

- T-600: Terminator
- Astro Boy: Astro Boy
- Vision: Marvel Comics/Avengers
- Bender: Futurama
- Brainiac: DC Comics/Superman

Row 2:

- C-3PO: Star Wars
- Clank: Ratchet and Clank
- Cyberman: Doctor Who
- Cylon Centurion: Battlestar Galactica (Original, but some of these models appear in the reimagined series as well)
- Awesome-O: South Park

Row 3:

- Gort: The Day the Earth Stood Still
- Rosie: The Jetsons
- Alpha 5: Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers
- Voltron: Voltron
- EVE: WALL-E

Row 4:

- Maschinemensch: Metropolis
- Optimus Prime: Transformers
- WALL-E: WALL-E
- Wheatley: Portal
- Marvin: The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Row 5:

- Miles Monroe: Sleeper
- Hal 9000: 2001: A Space Odyssey
- Iron Giant: The Iron Giant
- Robby the Robot: Forbidden Planet
- Pneuman: DC Comics/Tom Strong

Row 6:

- R2-D2: Star Wars
- Sentinel: Marvel Comics/X-Men
- ASIMO: Real life, not fictional
- H8: Dark Horse Comics/Magnus Robot Fighter
- Mega Man: Mega Man/Rock Man

---

Also, there is at least one error. The robot listed as "Alpha" is Alpha **5**, known primarily from Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers (whereas Power Rangers refers to a plethora of seasons and works, where Alpha 5 does not appear).

Comment: Actually haven't seen that image!

Comment: That's actually a different image!

Comment: @CandiedMango I came about it on accident. I was just searching "famous robots' trying to find your #6, and this popped up. Kismet!

Comment: Yar.  The numbering is so horrid that it doesn't really improve on the other answers.

Comment: +1 for doing a reverse image search that none of us thought to do!!  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Technically not a reverse image search, I found it by accident! I was only trying to find #6 to help out you guys. Based on this artist's other work, I didn't think I'd find a full-size version!

Comment: Regarding your final comment, Alpha 6 looks sufficiently similar to Alpha 5 that it could be intended to be either one or both. Additionally, combined, I count no less than 8 different seasons/series in which they appear. I think just saying, "Alpha" is a brief way of trying to cover them all, rather than any kind of error.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe, but it clearly looks like Alpha 5 to me. Alpha 6 had red dots in his visor by the eyes, and does not have the black line underneath his red visor portion, which Alpha 5 *does* have. Also, Alpha 5's head is not as chrome-y as 6's, and I think that'd stand out. But, it could be meant to represent all of them.

Comment: A good number of these do show up on [his website](http://iamdany.com/FAMOUS-ROBOTS)

Comment: @Dorus His website is already linked in the question.

Comment: @CreationEdge Yes, but you write "but this image of a poster isn't shown on his website." While technical true, it hint that the images itself aren't on his web site at all. My link points to the url where they are.

Comment: @Dorus Those are the exact images used for the question(it's where the OP got them from). The website does not list them with the names. You can edit the *question* to include the link if you want.

Answer (score 12):

## Here we go...

1. Terminator (from *Terminator* franchise, series T-n with n<1000)
2. Astro-Boy
3. Vision (Marvel Comics)
4. Asimo (*real* robot, seen in Honda commercials)
5. Mega-Man
6. H8 (*Valiant / Gold Key* comics)
7. Awesome-O as seen in *South Park*
8. Housekeeper Rosie (from *The Jetsons*)
9. Gort (from *The Day the Earth Stood Still*)
10. Pneuman (from *Tom Strong* comics)
11. Robby the Robot (from *The Forbidden Planet*)
12. Sentinel (from *X-Men* media)
13. Marvin (from the movie version of *Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy*)
14. Wheatley (from *Portal 2*)
15. Woody Allen in *Sleeper*
16. Maschinenmensch (from *Metropolis*)
17. Optimus Prime (from *Transformers*)
18. Wall-E
19. Alpha 5 from *Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers*
20. Voltron
21. EVE (from *Wall-E*)
22. C3PO (from *Star Wars*)
23. Bender (from *Futurama*)
24. Brainiac (Kryptonian robot from Superman comics and animated series)
25. Clank (from *Ratchet and Clank*)
26. Cyberman (from *Doctor Who*)
27. Cylon (from *Battlestar Galactica*)

Thanks @CandiedMango, @JasonBaker, @WadCheber, @Hypnosifl, and @HBhatia for assistance!

Comment: 21  is Eva from Wall-E

Comment: I would presume 3. is Vision from Marvel Comics / MCU

Comment: 20 is [Voltron.](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/560938416552939520/_jc9q1OR.png)

Comment: I would literally bet my lungs on #20 being Voltron.

Comment: 11 is Robby the Robot

Comment: Sorry, not *Lost in Space*; getting my robots mixed up

Comment: 27 = Cylon, Battlestar Galactica

Comment: 14 is Wheatley from *Portal 2*. 25 is Clank from *Ratchet &...*

Comment: 15 = Woody Allen in *Sleeper*

Comment: 10 is Pneuman from the "Tom Strong" comics by Alan Moore.

Comment: #4 is *not* Gort--Gort is #9, that's the name of the robot from The Day the Earth Stood Still.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : That's just an accident because of numbering issues with list mode...thanks!

Comment: For #19, it seems the robot's name is [Alpha 5](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Alpha_5). And #4, Asimo, isn't just a character from commercials, but also a real working robot that Honda uses as a demo model, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIMO).

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Good points...will add!

Answer (score 5):

1 Terminator (*The Terminator*)

2 Astroboy (*Astroboy*)

6 H8

7 Eric Cartman pretending to be Awesome-O (*South Park*)

8 <s>The Nanny Robot</s> Rosie (*The Jetsons*)

9 Gort (cheers @Wad) (*The Day the Earth Stood Still*)

11 Robby the Robot (*The Forbidden Planet*)

12 Sentinel (*X-Men*)

13 Marvin (*Hitchhicker's guide to the galaxy*)

14 Wheatley (*Portal*)

15 Woody Allen (*Sleeper*)

16 Maschinenmensch (*Metropolis*)

17 Optimus Prime (*Transformers*)

18 WALL-E (*WALL-E*)

19 Alpha 5 (*Power Rangers*)

20 Voltron (*Voltron)

21 EVE (*WALL-E*)

22 C-3PO (*Star Wars*)

23 Bender (*Futurama*)

25 Clank (*Ratchet & Clank*)

26 Cyberman (*Doctor Who*)

27 Cylon (*Battlestar Galactica*)

Comment: Ahem, #9 has a name.  That name is Gort.

Comment: 19 = Alpha, Power Rangers

Comment: Also fairly certain that 20 is from some season of PR and is a Megazord.

Comment: @WadCheber good call! There are many PRs I have not seen it just looked so similar :P

Comment: 12=Sentinel, X Men

Comment: @N_Soong Yeah, the parser respects the first number you use as a bullet, then automatically increments by one each time

Comment: 15 = Woody Allen in *Sleeper*

Answer (score 5):

1. Terminator - *Terminator*
2. Astro Boy - *Astro Boy*
3. ...
4. ...
5. Mega Man - *Mega Man*
6. ...
7. Awesome-O - *South Park*
8. Rosie - *The Jetsons*
9. Gort - *Day The Earth Stood Still*
10. ...
11. Robbie - *Forbidden Planet*
12. ...
13. Marvin - *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (movie)*
14. Wheatley - *Portal*
15. ...
16. (unnamed?) - *Metropolis*
17. Optimus Prime - *Transformers*
18. Wall-E - *Wall-E*
19. ...
20. Voltron - *Voltron*
21. Eve - *Wall-E*
22. C3PO - *Star Wars*
23. Bender - *Futurama*
24. ...
25. Clank - *Ratchet & Clank*
26. Cyberman - *Doctor Who*
27. Cylon - *Battlestar Galactica (original)*

Comment: #16 = Maschinenmensch from Metropolis

Comment: Bonus points for doing it without help.

Comment: Since a lot of the help comments on the other answers were from me, I authorize you to use them to flesh out your own answer.